# How to print ACE_thread_t using printf()

Tags: c++, portability, ace

ACE_OS::thr_self() returns ACE_thread_t. ACE logger has a switch "\t" to print it.
How can I do it if I want to print thread id by using printf()?

Answer (score 2):

If ACE doesn't provide a method to do it you have to figure out its type.  Given that it is ACE, it is probably hidden behind 3 typedefs nested in 5 #defines.  The header file `OS_NS_Thread.h` looks like as good a starting point as any.

Comment: If `ACE_thread_t` is like `pthread_t` it will boil down to either an integer ("%d" or "%x") or a pointer ("%p").  The rationale here is that these are (a) lightweight, and (b) unique.  This may not be the case.  It's possible `ACE_thread_t` will be a complex type.  If it's  public you may be able to get the id out of it.  If it's not there will be need to be some API call for you to get the actual thread id.  Be very careful with this though, because the type is likely different from platform to platform and there's no guarantee of portability.

Comment: +1 for "behind 3 typedefs nested in 5 #defines"! It's the ACE-style.

Answer (score 1):

ACE? C++? Why not use iostream instead of printf?

```
ACE_thread_t id = ACE_OS::thr_self();
unsigned char content[sizeof(id)];
size_t i;
memcpy(content, &id, sizeof(id) );
for (i=0; i<sizeof(id); ++i) printf("%02X",content[i]);
```

Comment: I dont get wy you've used it memcpy and loop here?